# What is the word for a personal out-of-place remark you make during a conversation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions, phrase-requests

What is the word for it when you make a remark, rather absent-mindedly during a conversation? It may be very significant for you personally or you may have been pondering over it, but it seems out of place in the conversation.

Comment: [*Non sequitur*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/non-sequitur), perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best word in this context is ***non sequitur***

> - A non sequitur (English pronunciation: /ˌnɒnˈsɛkwᵻtər/; Classical Latin: [noːn ˈsɛkᶣɪtʊr] "it does not follow") is a conversational and literary device, often used for comedic purposes. It is something said that, because of its apparent lack of meaning relative to what preceded it,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(literary_device)) seems absurd to the point of being humorous or confusing.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(literary_device))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a  ***gaffe***:

> - a remark or action that is a social mistake and not considered polite:
>     *I made a real gaffe - I called his new wife "Judy", which is the name of his ex-wife.
>     You started eating before anyone else had been served? What a gaffe!*

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Not really. A "gaffe" is definitely socially inappropriate or even impolite, even if only mildly so. Your own definition states this. "Non sequitur" is definitely preferable as it does carry these negative connotations.